# 12-lead ECG circuit diagram

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics, diy, ecg

I am trying to build 12 lead ECG circuit for my project, so could someone explain to me what should I do about allocating the electrodes on this diagram? Where do they need to be attached?

Source: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Circuit-diagram-of-ECG-monitor-for-each-of-the-twelve-leads_fig3_326377577

As on the post, it was written, that this diagram was "Circuit diagram of ECG monitor for each of the twelve leads", but I still don't really get how this could be accomplished referring to 10 electrodes.

[image]

Comment: You get 6 limb leads from 4 limb-connected electrodes.  As I mentioned on another of your questions, one ADC channel will measure (RA,LA) differentially and another will measure (RA,LL) differentially.  These are two of the sides of Einthoven's triangle (lead I and lead II if I recall correctly), and from them the third side (III) and the three augmented leads (aVL, aVR, aVF) may also be calculated.  That actually uses only 3 electrodes to get all 6 limb lead channels.  RL drive is used to reduce common-mode voltage, making 4.  And then each of the precordial leads (V1...V6) adds one electrode

Comment: So there are a total of 10 physical electrodes used in acquiring a 12-lead ECG.

Comment: I guess I should mention that in addition to controlling common-mode, RL drive can be used to detect open circuit on other electrodes (loose electrode)

Comment: In ECG-speak, a 'lead' is a pair of electrodes. Multiple leads can share electrodes. An electrode is a damp patch connected to the skin with a wire back to the machine. A lead is a logical measurement taken across two parts of the body.